# if statement causing jar to not run

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am trying to make a program that copies a file and then pastes it to another location, with the use of a few Apache IO methods. It works perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it to a JAR, the JAR doesn't run. The "Past Filepaths.txt" file is in my project folder. When I look in the Task Manager, I can see it start up for a few seconds, before it disappears. I've narrowed it down to a single `if` statement:

```
if (filePaths.length == 2){
        source.setText(filePaths[0]);
        dest.setText(filePaths[1]);
}
```

If I comment this out, the JAR runs. If I don't, it doesn't.

This is some very rough code I created in ~30 mins as a kind of script, to help me move some files around, so if it looks a little rough, I apologize.

My full code:

```
public class Main {
    private JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    private JTextField source, dest;
    private String sourcePath, destPath;

public Main() {
    String[] filePaths = null;
    try {
        filePaths = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Past Filepaths.txt"), "ASCII").split("~");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton jButton = new JButton("Update Files");

    source = new JTextField("", 40);
    dest = new JTextField("", 40);

    if (filePaths.length == 2){
        source.setText(filePaths[0]);
        dest.setText(filePaths[1]);
    }

    jButton.addActionListener( (e) -> {
        updateVars();
        updateFiles();
    });
    jf.setSize(500, 200);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.add(panel);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Source"));
    panel.add(source);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Destination"));
    panel.add(dest);
    panel.add(jButton);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}

private void updateVars(){
    sourcePath = source.getText();
    destPath = dest.getText();
}

private void updateFiles(){
    if(new File(sourcePath).exists() == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, sourcePath + " is not a valid file path!");
        return;
    }

    if(new File(destPath).exists() == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, destPath + " is not a valid file path!");
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(sourcePath), new File(destPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File pastFiles = new File("Past Filepaths.txt");
    try{
        FileUtils.write(pastFiles, sourcePath + "~", "ASCII");
        FileUtils.write(pastFiles, destPath, "ASCII", true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Past Filepaths.txt` in the directory that you're running from?  If it's not you'll end up with ... exactly the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes. It's in the project folder.

Comment: Could you start your jar from command line with `java -jar /path/to/jarfile`? That'll give helpful information.

Comment: Step through this with a debugger.  Make sure `filePaths` is what you expect.  I still firmly believe that it's not finding that file - in other words, you've put that file in a different directory from the one where you're running from.

Comment: @Krazor It says that `File 'Past Filepaths.txt' does not exist`. I don't know how I would fix that. When I try using `classLoader.getResource()` instead, it gives an error in Eclipse.

Comment: @DavidWallace You're correct. But how would I fix this?

Comment: `Past Filepaths.txt` being in your project folder doesn't mean anything. You're using relative paths, so it depends from where you run your JAR. Add a debug output to the top of your program and see if the resulting file path really exists: `System.out.println(new File("Past Filepaths.txt").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Quagaar's suggestion is excellent.  This will tell you where to put the file.  It needs to be in the directory that you are _running from_ - which may or may not be the same as your project directory.

Comment: For the love of humanity, don't put spaces in file names...

Comment: Yup, every time you put a space in a filename, a wombat dies.

Comment: Does it say nothing more than that? No null pointer whatsoever? How about refactoring and putting that 'if-statement' into your try/catch block as well? (With proper error handling, obviously)

Comment: @Bohemian It's almost 2017, I think we should be past "no spaces in filenames" by now

Comment: @Sentry Nope. Linux still can't handle spaces in file names.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam What? Of course Linux and its current filesystems support spaces. Sure, you may have to put stuff in quotes in bash commands, but only because space is used as separator by default (and that can be changed, too). But I think we are getting off-topic here.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam I think you'll find Linux CAN handle spaces in filenames.  But that doesn't mean you SHOULD use them.

Comment: @Sentry I am usually *for* having a daily crontab job that finds all files on disk with a space in their name and summarily deletes them. They are just a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a debugging problem, not a code problem per se. So, debug it.

Start the JVM in debug mode:

```
java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=y <rest of your startup command>
```

Note that `suspend=y` will halt execution until you connect your IDE to it.

Open your IDE and set a break point where you want execution to stop, connect your IDE to debug port `9999` (as per `address=9999`), then step through the code to see what's happening.